# SELECT - Split content of field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my table

```
id | email  | values
1  | a@a    | 2,3,
2  | b@b    | 1,3,
3  | c@c    | 2,
```

How to compare the numbers in the VALUES field with those in the ID

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = 'c@c' AND id NOT LIKE (each id column) ";
```

result = ID 1

Comment: Having multiple values in the VALUES field is not a good idea in the first place. Read up on database normalization and 1NF.

Comment: Select it all and let PHP sort it out. If the values were in a separate table bound to id it would have been a different mater.

Comment: If you really want to do it in SQL then [Read the manual - String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)

Comment: What result do you want ,"Each values of VALUES" isn't very clear.

Answer (score 2):

The points about database normalization are correct and very important:

- You should not be storing multiple values in one field.
- You should not be storing numbers as strings.
- You should properly declare all foreign key relationships, which you cannot do with such a list.
- SQL has pretty bad string processing capabilities.
- Table has this really great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table*.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad design decisions.  MySQL has a convenient workaround (too convenient in my opinion), called `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t.table WHERE email = 'c@c' AND
     find_in_set(t.id, values) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

This query find the id with a suffix comma in the values column. the Id can be either at the beginning or between the values column. This will also not return a row when id is 1 but the values is (21,3) or (2,31,) since values is always delimited by comma (,).

```
select *
from truck where email='c@abc.com'
and values not like concat(Id,',%')
and values not like concat('%,',Id,',%')
```

Comment: You're last concat should be `concat('%,',...`; otherwise smaller values will have issue when larger ones are present. Example: 3 with 13, 23, 103, etc....

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
 select * from yourtable
 where [values] like '%,'+cast(id as varchar)+',%' 
 or [values] like cast(id as varchar)+',%'
 or [values] like '%,'+cast(id as varchar)
```